# Entity Framework Delete DB InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Hey guys I can't seem to figure this one out. Any thoughts?

In my project I am attempting to use EF6 as my method for CRUD. When I am making unit tests for the data access section I am deleting a SQL Server compact DB and creating it from scratch to ensure a clean test. I am using the following code.

```
[SetUp]
public void Setup()
{
     //instantiate the test db that we will use to run persistence testing.
     Database.DefaultConnectionFactory = new SqlCeConnectionFactory("System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0");
     context = new RTBComicsDataContext(GetTestDbName());
     context.Database.Delete();
     context.Database.Create();
}
```

the test DB name function seen above returns the following:

```
"Data Source=" +(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)) + @"\\RTB.Data.Tests.Db.sdf;Persist Security Info=False";
```

This generates an Invalid Operation Exception when called, and I am not too sure why.

> Inner exception message: Sequence contains no matching element

Answer (score 0):

I figured out at least how to get around my issue. This appears to be something to do with having the tests saved to a sql server CE database on my local machine.

If I point this function at an ACTUAL sql server instance it works just fine.